# Tamanho limite do papel usando printer_draw_text php

Tags: php, impressora

Estou enfrentando um problema muito estranho na impressão em impressora térmica usando o php.

Ocorre tudo certo, porem quanto o texto é grande ele não imprimi tudo, tem um tamanho padrão da impressão. Não consegui achar nada a respeito.
Segue meu código

```
function imprimir($texto){

$handle = printer_open("Daruma DR800");

printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW",PRINTER_FORMAT_CUSTOM); 

printer_start_doc($handle, "Print"); // Name Document 

printer_start_page($handle);

$font = printer_create_font("Arial",40,16,PRINTER_FW_NORMAL,false,false,false,0);
printer_select_font($handle, $font);

$posicao = 10;
for($i = 0; $i < count($texto); $i++){
printer_draw_text($handle, $texto[$i], 10, $posicao);

$posicao = $posicao + 40;

}

printer_delete_font($font);

printer_end_page($handle);

printer_end_doc($handle);

printer_close($handle); 

}
```

A variável `$texto` é um array de strings.

Obs: Sei que php não é a melhor opção para impressão local, porem é a que preciso usar no projeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função `printer_draw_text` funciona assim:

```
printer_draw_text ( resource, string, posiçãoX, posiçãoY)
```

Você está aumentando de 40 em 40 e provavelmente depois de uma quantidade de texto é necessário usar:

```
$linhaAtual = 0; //usado apenas para checar a linha atual
$linhasPorPagina = 12; //Ajuste aqui para definir o limite de linhas por pag

for ($i = 0; $i < count($texto); $i++){

    if ($linhaAtual > $linhasPorPagina) {
        $linhaAtual = 0; //Linha atual da página volta para zero

        $posicao = 0; //Volta a posição para zero

        printer_end_page($handle); //Finaliza a página
        printer_start_page($handle); //Inicia uma nova página
    }

    printer_draw_text($handle, $texto[$i], 10, $posicao);

    $posicao = $posicao + 40;

    $linhaAtual++; //Soma mais uma linha
}

printer_delete_font($font);

printer_end_page($handle);
```

> **Nota:** nunca usei impressoras térmicas, eu sei como são, mas tecnicamente falando não sei se pra cada quantidade de papel será considerada uma página.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Faz sentido sim. Não estou em casa, vou testar mais tarde e falo se resolveu. Mas agradeço sua resposta.

Comment: @DenisDias ajustei o código de uma maneira que bastará você ajustar na variável `$linhasPorPagina` o limite de linha por página.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Estou com medo só da impressora imprimir quando eu fechar a pagina. Mas depois das 18:00 vou testar.

Comment: @DenisDias ainda bem que você me alertou, apesar de ser uma situação diferente agora que percebi que o script poderia gerar um página vazia no final, então mudei a ordem da `IF`, só passei pra avisar mesmo.

Comment: Deu certo. Muito obrigado

Comment: Ressuscitando o tópico. Estou desenvolvendo um sistema, do qual o cliente irá imprimir a nota fiscal pelo Daruma. Eles oferecem alguma API ou você que desenvolveu o código?

Comment: @JM_2021 o código acima usa a API instalada via PECL para PHP, infelizmente essa API foi descontinuada e removida. O código acima é apenas um exemplo de uso de como usar a API. Note que PHP em websites roda em um servidor e não na máquina do usuário, se você estiver tentando acessar a impressora via navegador, com PHP não vai dar certo, a não ser que o servidor esteja na mesma rede ou computador que a página web for aberta.

Comment: Se o objetivo for imprimir via servidor mesmo então você pode usar fopen() para abrir a porta da impressora, e usar fwrite() para enviar as instruções da sua impressora, desde que tenha o manual de como usar tais *instruções* dentro do fwrite()